# Question: Does AWS offer an API endpoint to access the DMS mapping-rules for a database migration task?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-dms

**Question**: Does AWS offer an API endpoint to access the DMS mapping `rules` for a database migration task?

**Problem**: I need to programmatically retrieve a database migration task's mapping `rules` to determine whether a replication task has a `filter-type` rule on a source table. The output is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Selections.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.Filters.html). Essentially, DMS migration tasks can be problematic when reading from PostgreSQL and a source filter is applied on a column that is not a primary key, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Limitations).

**Work attempted**:
In `AWS DMS -> Database Migration Tasks -> <TaskName>` there is a tab for `Mapping rules`. I have checked [DatabaseMigrationServices](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dms.html) for Boto3 and ran through the `describe_endpoint` and `describe_replication_tasks` endpoints, but I did not find any `rules` in the result outputs. I think I have exhausted internet search results, and now am asking a question here.

**Expected result**:

I am looking for a JSON output similar to below. Is it possible to pull this data programmatically? If yes, how?

```
{
    "rules": [{
        "rule-type": "selection",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "1",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "test",
            "table-name": "employee"
        },
        "rule-action": "include",
        "filters": [{
            "filter-type": "source",
            "column-name": "empid",
            "filter-conditions": [{
                "filter-operator": "gte",
                "value": "100"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code in lambda. If you print the response you wont able to see the Table mappings but you can in cloudwatch log

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dms = boto3.client('dms')
    response = dms.describe_replication_tasks(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'replication-task-id',
                'Values': [
                    'test'
                ]
            }
        ],
        WithoutSettings=False)
    table_mappings = response['ReplicationTasks'][0]['TableMappings']
    
 
    return table_mappings
```